# How to get higher resolution in topography map

Tags: python, resolution, matplotlib-basemap

I need to make a topographical map, but so far the resolution is not high enough with 'resolution=f'. Is there better way to make higher resolution? Appreciate that in advance.
[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import pandas as pd

minlon = -95
maxlon = -91
minlat = 17
maxlat = 20

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 12))
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='f', llcrnrlat=minlat, urcrnrlat=maxlat, llcrnrlon=minlon, urcrnrlon=maxlon)

m.etopo()

m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a high resolution etopo background in matplotlib Basemap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768777/how-to-draw-a-high-resolution-etopo-background-in-matplotlib-basemap)